# Trying to merge all text files in a folder and append file as well

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to merge all text files in a folder.  I have this part working, but when I try to append the file name before the contents of each text file, I'm getting a error that reads: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

The code below must be pretty close, but something is definitely off.  Any thoughts what could be wrong?

```
import glob

folder = 'C:\\my_path\\'

read_files = glob.glob(folder + "*.txt")

with open(folder + "final_result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(f)
            outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.close
```

Comment: If you can use the commandline, then here's a oneliner: `cat *.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outfile.write(f)` seems to be your problem because you opened the file with in binary mode with `'wb'`. You can convert to bytes using `encode` You'll likely not want to close `outfile` in your last line either (although you aren't calling the function anyway). So something like this might work for you:

```
import glob

folder = 'C:\\my_path\\'

read_files = glob.glob(folder + "*.txt")

with open(folder + "final_result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(f.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: No, no, that's what I already have.  I want to add the name of the file I am copying text from, right before each file that is merged.  So, name of file #1...all text from file #1, name of file #2...all text from file #2, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Oh I see. I just edited to clarify that you are in 'binary' mode with `'wb'`. You can encode your string as byte in that case.

Comment: Yeap, yeap, that works.  Thanks for the help with this thing!!